# Assign bathymetry to raster map

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a fishing zone between Latitudes 20°N and 26°N and I want to assign bathymetry to each square of the resolution 5 nautical miles (Or 1 nautical mile).
I tried the next R code but I get positive bathymetry inside the ocean which is wrong.

```
marmap::getNOAA.bathy(xmin ,
                      xmax ,
                      ymin ,
                      ymax ,
                      resolution = 5)
```

Where xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax represent the limits of the zone.

Is there any other solution that you suggest?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you reversed longitudes and latitudes. the syntax of `getNOAA.bathy` is as follows:

```
getNOAA.bathy(lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2, resolution)
```

If your longitudes are located to the West of the greenwich meridian, they should also be negative.

Finally, you might get a "could not reach NOAA servers" error message when using `getNOAA.bathy()` since the NOAA removed the server on which the function used to make its queries up until very recently. We are working on a fix and should be releasing it on github and on CRAN servers in the next few days.

Comment: I don't think I reverse it. xmin and xmax correspond to longitude min and max, and you're right it's negative, and ymin and ymax correspond to latitudes. Thanks for the info about new releasing.

Comment: You should try to post the actual code you're typing as a minimal reproducible example. It will be easier and quicker for us to give you useful answers.